# Can anyone help me installation Mosquitto 2.0 on CentOS linux 7.0

Tags: centos, mqtt

I need to install Mosquitto 2.0 on my centOS linux machine.

The command available is **yum install mosquitto** works well, but it installs 1.6 version

I cannot use docker due to some limitation in my machine container eligibility.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: This sort of question is probably off topic for Stack Overflow, it might be acceptable on SuperUser. Mosquitto is pretty easy to build from source, if you get stuck doing that then a question showing what you've tried and how it fails may be on topic here.

Comment: If so, could you please help me in that as it seems I am not an expert like you in MQTT stuff. You help or any document will be highly appreciated

Comment: Would you mind using ``snap`` store?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error along with performing this is the best document I got so far.

https://www.disk91.com/2016/technology/internet-of-things-technology/install-mosquitto-mqtt-server-on-centos-to-publish-iot-data/